# File size grows each time software deployed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment

I have developed a desktop application in VS 2010 (.net framework 4) for x86 platform. Each time i build the setup file and deploy it and see it in add/remove program, i see the file size increasing. I didn't add new code in my project, i only changed the design of crystal report.
When i checked the program's folder size in C:\Programfiles\ and it was only 22.6 M.B. and in add/remove program it's size was 1.77 G.B.
I have no idea why is this happening??

[image].
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The file you are looking at in your Program Files folder is probably not the only file you are deploying. A closer examination of your Setup project will probably help you to see what else is being deployed:

- Click on the arrow [image: Arrow Image] to the left of your Setup project in Visual Studio. Then click the arrow next to Detected Dependencies (if it's there). Everything listed there also has to be deployed, unless it is marked excluded: [image: Excluded Icon]
- Next, right-click on the Setup project, go to view, and click File System. Click on each folder to see what is being deployed there. Assuming that you used mostly default settings in this Setup project, this probably represents the bulk of what is being deployed. One of these files is probably growing when you make your changes.
  [image: Select File System]

Comment: You should have the ability to add the images now.

Comment: @JBelter: Thanks. Images have been added.